# Convert dynamic urls to static [SEO]

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I need to make some urls static for SEO improvements on my site. I was able to work out some simple URLs, but the following ones are giving me a lot of trouble. I'm new with this kind of stuff.

I write some rules for the following urls, but I wasn't able to make them work.

I've the following URLs

**Dynamic URLs**

```
http://www.site.net/project.php?projectid=2
http://www.site.net/project.php?projectid=2&do=issuelist
http://www.site.net/project.php?projectid=2&do=issuelist&issuetypeid=bug
```

I would like to make them static urls to get something like this:

**Static URLs**

```
http://www.site.net/project-2.html
http://www.site.net/project-2/do-issuelist/
http://www.site.net/project-2/do-issuelist/type-bug.html
```

**Params data type**

**projectid:** *numeric*

**do:** *text*

**issuetypeid:** *text*

My hosting is running Linux, so I need this for Apache, not IIS.

What would be the url rewrite rules for **.htaccess**?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following structure instead:

```
http://www.site.net/project/2
http://www.site.net/project/2/issuelist
http://www.site.net/project/2/issuelist/bug
```

This way you can make the `/project/` path a reserved term (so long as you don't currently have and never plan to have an actual top-level directory named "project" on your site). This avoids having to use multiple RewriteCond directives to check that the request is not for a valid file or directory every time.

If this pattern suits you, then the following rules ought to do the trick in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)$ /project.php?projectid=$1
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /project.php?projectid=$1&do=$2
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /project.php?projectid=$1&do=$2&issuetypeid=$3
```

The above RewriteRule patterns allow for the `do` and `issuetypeid` values to contain lowercase, uppercase, digits, underscores and hyphens, but you should modify the patterns to suit the actual constraints your site allows for these variables.